# How to display the first data in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

How to display the first data in ng-repeat

```
<div class = "panel-body">
<div ng-repeat=" img in images">
    <img src="http://photo/{{img.path}}" alt="">
</div>
Panel content
```

example sql
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Customers;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ng-if="$index == 0"`

See below

```
<img ng-if="$index == 0" ng-src="http://photo/{{img.path}}" alt="" />
```

Comment: thank all, success,

    <div ng-repeat=" img in ht.images" ng-if="$first">
or
  <div ng-repeat=" img in ht.images" ng-if="$index == 0">

@gaurav bhavsar,@Łukasz

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fetch only one record then use it like this. No need for ng-repeat.

Or still if you want to use, then use $index.

```
<div class = "panel-body">
  <div ng-repeat=" img in images">
    <img src="http://photo/{{images[0].path}}" alt="">
 </div>
```

Comment: would this work? I think in this case, `img` would reference each property of the first element in images, not the image itself

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the first data, you shouldn't need ngRepeat, just reference it by its index `images[0]`:

```
<img ng-src="http://photo/{{images[0].path}}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$first` variable:

`<img ng-if="$first" ng-src="http://photo/{{img.path}}" alt="" />`

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat