# How to display the selected data in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

how to display the data based on the selected, 
where the ng-repeat?

.. ng-repeat=" img in ht.images **where id in (1,2,3)**">

```
<div class = "panel-body">
<div ng-repeat=" img in images">
    <img src="http://photo/{{img.path}}" alt="">
</div>
Panel content
```

example in sql:

> SELECT * FROM Images WHERE Id IN (1,2);

---

**UPDATE:** 
example in sql SELECT * FROM Images WHERE Id IN (1,2,3);

I tried at ng-repeat, but it makes a lot of work to rewrite the code

```
    <div ng-repeat=" img in ht.images" ng-if="$index==0">
        <img ng-src="http://photos.com/foler/{{img.path}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat=" img in ht.images" ng-if="$index==1">
        <img ng-src="http://photos.com/foler/{{img.path}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat=" img in ht.images" ng-if="$index==2">
        <img ng-src="http://photos.com/foler/{{img.path}}" alt="">
    </div>
```

---

```
    "images": [{
    "path": "00/abc1.jpg",
    "order": 1
    }, {
    "path": "00/abc2.jpg",
    "order": 2
    }, {
    "path": "00/abc3.jpg",
    "order": 3
    }]
```

the previous question [How to display the first data in ng-repeat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727218/how-to-display-the-first-data-in-ng-repeat)

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"? What exactly do you want to do? Please be more explicit.

Comment: I want to display as the SQL IN Operator, 
ng-repeat=" img in images" WHERE Id IN (1,2)

Comment: you can create a filter

Comment: @dulgan Consider approving the answer that has been useful to you.

Comment: I tried from the answers but can not be applied, 
ng-if = "$ index == 0" can get the first one, but I need to get 3 data only from lists, sample ng-if = "$ index == 0,1,2"

Comment: @dulgan have you checked mine ! it works for sure!

Comment: @dulgan your second code on "update" section doesn't make sense. `ng-repeat` is a loop. Why do you want to check the $index?

Comment: @dulgan see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc). Basically:

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

**UPDATE**:

Here is a simple code showing several images:

**AngularJS**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("ctrl", ['$scope', function ($scope){
    $scope.images = [{
    "path": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg",
    "order": 1
    }, {
    "path": "http://newsitems.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/2-36.jpeg",
    "order": 2
    }, {
    "path": "https://www.cesarsway.com/sites/newcesarsway/files/styles/large_article_preview/public/Common-dog-behaviors-explained.jpg?itok=FSzwbBoi",
    "order": 3
    }];
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="img in images">
      <img ng-src="{{img.path}}" ></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you can [see the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lcdjcu30/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ganideveloper/pac4syrt/5/


I'll show you three pictures, how to take three pictures in each list images

Comment: That it is not the original question.  Anywere, you could nested ng-repeat directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-show and ng-src instead of src directive:

```
<div class = "panel-body">
   <div ng-show="img.id == 1 || img.id == 2" ng-repeat="img in images">
      <img ng-src="http://photo/{{img.path}}" alt="">
   </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Your answers are correct approach my case, but I will use this method for a while,<div ng-repeat=" img in ht.images" >
    <img  ng-if="$index==0 " ng-src="http://photos.com/floder/{{img.path}}" alt="" >
    <img   ng-if="$index==1 " ng-src="http://photos.com/floder/{{img.path}}" alt="" >
    <img   ng-if="$index==2 " ng-src="http://photos.com/floder/{{img.path}}" alt="" >
</div>

Answer (score 0):

here is the controller part :

```
    $scope.selectedId = [1,2,3];

    $scope.filterById = function(img) {
        return ($scope.selectedId.indexOf(img.id) !== -1);
    };
```

here is the html

```
<div ng-repeat="img in images | filter:filterById ">
    <img ng-src="http://photo/{{img.path}}" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check in controller where id is forexample 1 then insert to another list then reapet this list in html